# Override a CSS Class

Tags: javascript, css, web

I have created a few classes in my javascript file that will be essentially referenced in the CSS file as "tr.Yes" "tr.No" and the new one "tr.override".

I want to override the values of tr.Yes and tr.No with tr.override due to a few added constraints in the JS file. Basically, how would I override them with tr.override that has a background of green?

Thanks guys.

My CSS so far looks as follows:

```
tr.Yes td.IndicatedDispatch {
background: yellow;
}

tr.No td.IndicatedDispatch {
background: red;
}
```

Comment: Could you post a jsFiddle with what you have so far?

Comment: Just place the CSS rules for `tr.override` after `tr.yes`

Comment: added CSS code above. I don't think any javascript code is necessary here.

Comment: Is that really the CSS? Where's `tr.No`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `override` class to override the `yes` and `no` classes define your `override`class after the other ones in your CSS file and redefine the same rules with different values.

Like this

```
tr.Yes td.IndicatedDispatch {
background: red;
}

tr.Override td.IndicatedDispatch {
background: green; /* Redefine here*/
}
```

Comment: maybe utilize !important

Comment: @DanceSC, NO! Just let the **Cascade** Style Sheets, cascade over previous rules.

Comment: @DanceSC !important should be avoided whenever it s possible. Here it is not needed

Comment: yeah, I edited it to maybe for that same reason. It is extremely situational.

Comment: you are right. will check mark you when time is up. Thanks a ton, works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You can override CSS declarations by making them **more specific**. Go higher up the DOM.

```
tr.Yes td.IndicatedDispatch {
  background: yellow;
}
```

becomes:

```
table tr.Yes td.IndicatedDispatch {
  background: red;
}
```

Related article: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: A sneaky way to increase specificity is to add a class twice: `tr.Yes.Yes` is more specific than `tr.Yes`

Comment: Cool, Pointy. I never knew that.

Comment: @Diodeus I just read about it the other day :) [Here's the link.](http://csswizardry.com/2014/07/hacks-for-dealing-with-specificity/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to add the override class and leave the original classes, you create a combination rule like this:

```
tr.Yes td.IndicatedDispatch {
    background: yellow;
}

tr.No td.IndicatedDispatch {
    background: red;
}

tr.Yes.override td.IndicatedDispatch , 
tr.No.override td.IndicatedDispatch {
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS works from top to bottom, i.e selector1 css attributes will be overridden by selector1 css attributes defined at last(MORE SPECIFIC). For example

```
.myClass{
color: #000000;
}
/*
* Some other code
* 
*/

.myClass{
color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

So at run time `color:#FFF` color will be picked up.

Answer (score -1):

You could change your selectors to `tr.Yes:not(.override)` so that they do not take effect when the override class is in effect.  Otherwise, both the `tr.Yes` and the `tr.override` styling will be merged, and anything from `tr.Yes` that is not overridden by `tr.override` will remain.